# How do I partially compare deeply nested objects in Cypress assertions?

Tags: cypress, chai, web-api-testing

I'm using [Cypress](https://www.cypress.io) as my automation framework for both API and UI tests. I've written multiple API tests that are running and passing but they're only validating that the `response.status` returns a `200`. I want to compare the response json from a `GET` against a stored "expected" response to confirm that the JSON response data is correct.

I've tried different variations of `to.deep.equal` and `deepEquals` in my `.then(response => {}` code block. But I don't want to validate that just one field is returning the correct value, I want to validate whether a bunch of different fields are returning the correct values. My `GET` request returns over 100 lines of nested JSON fields/values and I only want to validate 20 or so fields/values nested inside each other.

```javascript
cy.request({
    method: 'GET',
    log: true,
    url: 'https://dev.api.random.com/calculators/run-calculate/524/ABC',

    headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json',
        'x-api-key': calcXApiKey
    },
    body: {}
}).then(response => {
    const respGet = response.body
    const tPrice = response.body.data.calculations.t_costs[0].comparison.t_price
    cy.log(respGet, tPrice)
    assert.deepEqual({
        tPrice
    }, {
        t_price: '359701'
    })
       // assert.equal(response.status, 200) -- This works great
})
```

Error= `expected { tPrice: undefined } to deeply equal { t_price: 359701 }`

Comment: For any future searchers, there's a thing called [deepInclude](https://www.chaijs.com/api/assert/#method_deepinclude) besides `deepEqual`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example, you're comparing object `{ tPrice: tPrice }` with `{ t_price: '359701' }`, that's why it's always going to fail because the keys are  different (apart from the fact that the `tPrice` variable value is `undefined`).

If you're already storing the *actual* value in a variable, there's no need to make an object out of it and use `deepEqual`. You can do:

```
const tPrice = response.body.data.calculations.t_costs[0].comparison.t_price
assert.equal(tPrice, '359701');
```

As to your other question, if I understand it correctly, your response looks like:

```
{
  data: {
    calculations: {
      t_costs: [
        { comparison: { t_price: "1111" } },
        { comparison: { t_price: "2222" } },
        { comparison: { t_price: "3333" } },
        { comparison: { t_price: "4444" } },
        /* ... */
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

And you want to assert just a few of those `t_costs` objects.

For that it's best to use a chai plugin such as [debitoor/chai-subset](https://github.com/debitoor/chai-subset).

To set it up:

```sh
npm install --save-dev chai-subset
```

In your `cypress/support/index.js`:

```js
const chai = require('chai');
const chaiSubset = require('chai-subset');
chai.use(chaiSubset);
```

In your spec:

```js
/* ... */
expect( response.body.data.calculations.t_costs )
    .to.containSubset([
        { comparison: { t_price: "1111" } },
        { comparison: { t_price: "3333" } }
    ]);
```

Comment: This worked great. Thank you so much for your help. It's so much simpler than I was making it haha.

Comment: Keep in mind, `chai-subset` works but error reporting is terrible. You need to manually analyze why it's failing. There is no explicit error of where field doesn't match.

Answer (score 2):

I was working on a very similar problem recently.  I often forget that Cypress comes bundled with some decent packages; in this case Lodash which is good at dealing with arrays and objects such as a deeply nested JSON API return.  I also had an expected return JSON that I wanted to compare to the full response JSON.  After a bit of trial and error I did this:

```
expect(Cypress._.isMatch(response.body, expectedReturn)).to.be.true;
```